# Backup only the File Allocation Table with the intention of recovering the files

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, backup

I'm not an expert in file systems. However, I know that (I might be wrong) each file has an entry in FAT and when you delete the file the operating system just marks that file as "Deleted" and that's the whole story for file recovery software.

Now I want to know, is there software (free or paid) to just backup this table?

So if I back up the FAT table, delete a bunch of files (maybe even most of the files), and don't write anything on the disk, I can easily restore the deleted files just by restoring the FAT.

Comment: What would be the _practical use_ of such software, though? While this is technically possible to do, I can't really think of a situation where you'd already have a way to guard against overwrites, but not against deletions...

Answer (score 0):

Software recommendation are out of scope on Superuser, but that is basically how any recovery software works anyway. As long as the content of the file is not overwritten it can be recovered. A "backup" of the file allocation table won't give you any benefit.

This being said, I never heard of this feature at least not in a consumer software. But if you want to do it anyway (for other reasons the file recovery) saving a file allocation into a separate file isn't that difficult. Since the FAT is located at the beginning of a FAT partition (after the boot sector) you could just copy the appropriate data blocks. You'll find extensive description on the file allocation table on the net. Just give it a try and ask a more specific question if you run into problems.